# How do I manage Django migrations when commiting changes from local development to remote?

Tags: django, version-control, django-migrations

During Django development, I have to create many migrations to get to what I'm looking for. For example, I might change the name of a field and later decide to set it back to what it was. So a lot of my migrations are just toying with the ORM.

I assume I don't need them all to show up in the remote repo (which might be a wrong assumption!).

I know excluding the migrations via .gitignore is not the right way.
Also can't include random ones in commits as they are all linked to one another.

So far, I [squash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#squashmigrations) my migrations each time I made changes:

```sh
squashmigrations app_label [start_migration_name] migration_name
```

and then commit.

What would be a better solution?

Comment: The methods you'll use here are the same regardless of what underlying VCS you might use (SVN, Mercurial, Git, bzr, etc), so Git isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is good.

Another solution, if your changes are just local, is to manually delete the new migrations and run `makemigrations` again.

Last but not least, if your concern is performance, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) says you shouldn't worry:

> You are encouraged to make migrations freely and not worry about how many you have; the migration code is optimized to deal with hundreds at a time without much slowdown.